# Display link to Careers Profile in Accounts tab

Tags: discussion, jobs, linked-accounts

Would it be possible to display a link to my Careers profile in the Accounts tab.

I realise not everybody may want this so maybe it could be enabled/disabled via the Prefs tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the "About Me" section of your profile exists an area where you can write *anything* about yourself that you want to share with the world.  This is the one area where you are encouraged to promote yourself.

Thus, this feature more or less exists on a per user basis.  If you want your Career profile to be visible, you could post it there.  For users who don't want this information listed, they can easily omit it.

Comment: Yes I knew about the about me section but I was hoping for something built in with the accounts section. I'll just use said section instead.

Comment: @Barry we don't do it automatically because many users only want it to be visible to people they send it to.