# Link from SO user profile to careers profile

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow, jobs, profile-page

Careers allows you to create a public profile page where you can publish your resume, best SO answers, etc., allowing you to link *from careers* to your SO answers and your SO profile, but there's no *good, easy* way to link the other direction.

For people actively looking for a job or open to options, **letting the user link from their SO profiles to their Careers page would be a *great* way to drive traffic to their Careers profile.** At least for me, my SO profile page currently ranks a lot better than my careers profile page on Google and linking this direction would bring a lot of traffic to careers.

I envision a "Display my Resume" checkbox in SO that adds a big orange "See my resume" button in the SO profile page. <sub>(ok, maybe not that big... or orange)</sub>

A second suggestion would be to at least let the user link it's careers profile to stackexchange "network profile".

<sub>I'm sorry if this already been proposed (I searched, really! But the only [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88100/display-link-to-careers-profile-in-accounts-tab) I could find accepted an answer which is not what I'm really looking for).</sub>

<sub>Ps: The mentioned [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88100/display-link-to-careers-profile-in-accounts-tab) was answered with something like "Just put a link to your career profile in About me". Although this is a fair answer, what I'm asking here is if anyone else thinks that a deeper kind of integration would be useful.</sub>

Comment: You did notice the *edit* link allowing you to add a huge, heading-sized link to Careers to your user profile?

Comment: @DanielBeck - The hope would be for better integration than just a big link in the About Me box.

Comment: Precisely. @cdeszaq, thank you for editing and bringing attention to this post.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and the Developer Story as of March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other questions are correct, the only way to do it right now is to add a link to your public profile. That said, we are working on being able to showcase your careers profile on your SO profile but I don't have an ETA.

See - [The profile page is getting a makeover (Part One)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226177/the-profile-page-is-getting-a-makeover)

Comment: To anyone wondering... We now have a big orange "Stack Overflow Careers profile" button :).