# StackOverflow profile doesn't find Careers profile, despite "Discover" link pointing there

Tags: support, jobs, profile-page

I've seen questions like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91557/link-from-so-user-profile-to-careers-profile) whose answers seem to suggest that linking your SO profile to your Careers profile was (being) implemented last year.

However, on my SO profile, the "Stack Overflow Careers Profile" under "Web Presence" says "No Careers profile for this account...", and yet, clicking the "Discover Stack Overflow Careers" link (as instructed) brings up my Careers profile.

Is this a bug?  If not, how can I get my profile linked up properly/fully?

Comment: try swapping the careers profile from private to public and back again.

Comment: @RobertLongson, it's already public, but I'll try swapping anyway.

Comment: Interesting, now it says "Found, but hidden" even though it's public again already.  Oh, I see, that means now I can link it.  OK, it worked, thanks!

Comment: Tried toggling private/public few times, but still not available on my SO profile.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs mine has been working ever since, so don't know what else to suggest, but hopefully someone else does...

Answer (score 3):

Toggle the careers profile private/public status twice.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Remember that after doing this, you must edit your profile on StackOverflow and check the box labeled "Show Careers link on my profile".